# Displaying name (data from mySQL) on the main page using php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Good day everyone, 
Firstly let me explain a little bit about my page flow, btw Im using PHP:-

1. User will Login to the page using their ID (NRIC No) with pw
2. Then, In the Main page I would like to display their full name (Eg: Welcome, **fullname**) whereby the name will automatically fetched from the same table with the nric no in the database.

I was successfully do that when I used the same attribute (fullname) with the ID. **However**, my sv wants the login ID using NRIC No. SO, When I edit the code, there is nothing appear in the main page :(

**Here are my codes in the main page**;

```
    <!-- logged in user information -->
    <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['namapengguna'])) : ?>
        <p style="margin-left:360px;margin-right:60px">Welcome<strong><?php echo $_SESSION['namapengguna'];  ?></strong></p>
    <?php endif ?>
```

***The information(NRIC No, full name) in the database was successfully inserted.
Example of my Table in database:-

namapengguna | idpengguna | password |

Maisarah     | 1234567891 | dfsdfdsf |

This is code for login:-

```
// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $idpengguna = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['idpengguna']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($idpengguna)) {
        array_push($errors, "Masukkan ID Pengguna");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Masukkan Kata Laluan");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE idpengguna='$idpengguna' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['idpengguna'] = $idpengguna;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "";
            header('location: lamanutama.php');
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "ID Pengguna/Kata Laluan salah");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you editing? What is the response you are getting while fetching fullname?

Comment: On a successful sign in your user's data should be put in the user's session. That way you don't have to query for a name or email every time you want to use it.

Comment: Basically im just adding the above code, When I use name as login id, the name will appear in the main page. But when I changed the id using the NRIC no, nothing appear. I hope you get what Im saying. :)

Comment: You should post your table structure and the code you are using to query the table with the NRIC number.

Comment: For now, there is nothing wrong with the login session, everything was fine, only the Welcome, fullname doesnt apppear. TQ

Comment: My post was edited. I hope you guys can help me, Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 session_start();
 // to store session values
 $_SESSION['namapengguna']= $idpengguna;  // Initializing Session with value of PHP Variable
?>
```

Main page Code:

```
echo $_SESSION["namapengguna"];
```

please visit this link best example for it. [here](http://www.eggslab.net/php-login-script/)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have session you can easily write like this
first add session_start(); and change namepenguna to idpenguna because it has to be the same session you set the time you were receiving result form mysql result

```
echo 'welcome' .$_SESSION['idpengguna'];
```

I hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

In your database , password column is not encode by md5(dfsdfdsf), but `$password = md5($password);`.You should check it

Answer (score 0):

try like  this, i hope it will help you:

```
<?php  if (isset($_SESSION['namapengguna'])){
     echo 'welcome' .$_SESSION['idpengguna'];
  }

  ?>
```